# Merge shapes in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I used cmd+J for two perfectly symmetric shapes to join them (points are tied to the pixel grid and that shapes are close to each other with no space between). Works fine if we'll use fill color. But something weird happens when I set the stroke:
[image]

How to merge / unite two shapes in Photoshop to avoid that?
I found only one way to fix that: overlap one shape over another, but it won't work if we'll have more complicated shapes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you merged the shapes <sup><sub>(width Cmd+E I would assume)</sub></sup> is just fine. It just needs another step. You merged 2 `shapes` into one, but your `shape` still contains 2 separate `paths`

---

You need to have one of the shape tools active. For example `Path selection tool` <kbd>A</kbd>. And obviously the correct shape layer.

In `Path operations`, choose `Merge Shape Components`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I didn't notice it for years.

Comment: @Semerukhin These things happen. If I remember correctly, it used to be a separate button in cs3.